# Irregular shape with projections and recesses that interlock with other shapes

Tags: single-word-requests, analogy

What might be a word for the shape with a lot of random projections and recesses? I would like to describe the shape of countries in Europe where countries have interlocking shapes like distorted jigsaw puzzles. Alternatively, what would be an analogy for irregular shape with female and male connections?

The analogies which come to my mind are:

- irregular jigsaw puzzle
- inkblot, puddle, blood pool
- amoeba with its tentacles (pseudopods)

Comment: I do like *fractal*.  You can also say that the coastlines are *irregular, with peninsulas and fjords."  You can say that the borders aren't smooth, straight lines.  You can say that the borders have a protuberations and fingers.

Comment: @aparente001 You mean: protuberances. :) Sorry....

Comment: I think you got off on the wrong foot. European country borders are not "interlocking". If they were, so would all others. They are just shaped irregularly.  Like most countries in the world.

Comment: I used European borders as an example in opposite to North America or Africa borders. In Europe, the borders are have been shaped by swords and gunpowder in opposite to North America or Africa where the borders resulted from signed agreements.

Comment: @aparente001 I like your analogy to an island with "peninsulas and fjords." Do you think that English words like "capes and bays" may be more widely understood?

Comment: Nice video at https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PkpMEkC1WcI confirming "swords and gunpowder" comment.

Comment: Hard for me to say.  I lived at the point of a fjord once.  I don't know how aware most people are of fjords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects or shapes which *intentionally* connect are generally described as "*interlocking*".

> This jigsaw puzzle has 1,000 interlocking pieces.

*Lego* bricks are also described this way.

A similar alternative would be *interlinking*.

Answer (score -1):

The borders between countries may be ***fractal*** in nature.

> Mandelbrot coined the term “fractal” to describe shapes (such as
>   country borders) that exhibit self similarity at different levels of
>   magnification.

from [Software Estimation in the Fractal Dimension](https://codeburst.io/software-estimation-in-the-fractal-dimension-914569e2ccb9)

(A [Penrose tile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling) also came to mind. However, these are regular, interlocking, repeated shapes, not like European countries).

Comment: country borders are not a good example of fractals.

Comment: I am very grateful for mentioning Mr. Penrose.

Comment: @Lambie, I agree that the U.S. / Canada border and the South Korean / North Korean border follow latitude great circles and are not fractal. However, please take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_border_rivers in the Europe section. You might observe that many European borders are defined by rivers. Some are defined by mountain ranges. These irregular natural phenomena are fractal (see "Software Estimation" quote). Since rival governments used these natural phenomena in determining borders, one can infer that those country borders are fractal.

Comment: Fractals are a system of representation. They are not things in the real. Fractals are used in picture compression, etc. https://mathigon.org/world/Fractals

Comment: I do not agree that borders are fractal. Fractals are structured, not random. They have repetitive patterns like a snowflake. I am looking for a random amoeba-shape which would be smooth after magnifying.

Comment: Przemyslaw Remin and @Lambie, Rather than debate the meaning of the word "fractal" here, I've created a question on the appropriate forum at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3268557/5220 . Since your answers to that  question would be "no" (=Country borders are NOT fractal), would you please post your "no" answer and let the mathematics community evaluate your response?

Comment: @rajah9 Unfortunately, no. I wouldn't dare join that forum. This is not a math issue. It is a linguistics and semiological/semiotics issue.

Comment: @rajah9 Thanks for posting the question. It seems that mathematicians express their common opposition against naming national borders as fractals. "No, international boundaries—even those which follow natural features, such as ridges and rivers—are not fractal." Fractal has associations with snowflakes for them. I can only add that I had experience walking in the mountains along the border. The border posts were located about 1 kilometer away. In the presumption, the border runs in straight lines between these posts.